# How to put a number in superscript, ggplot2 axis title

Tags: r, ggplot2, superscript

Hi I'm wanting to put the following title on the x-axis of my graph

**Growth (cm d-1)**

However I'm trying to get the -1 in superscript and am having difficulties doing this

I'm currently putting the title as y= in the labs section of my ggplot code)

eg.,

`labs(color = "group 1", x = "group 2", y = "Growth (cm d-1)")`

Just wondering if anyone knows how to make the -1 superscript

Comment: You may want to try something like this:  `labs(color = expression(group[1])`

Comment: Also possible with ggtext: https://wilkelab.org/ggtext/